# String comparison returns wrong result

Tags: java, android, string, string-comparison

I trying to compare 2 strings in Java to determine if they are the same:

```
System.out.println("app version: "+ appversion + " latest version: "+ latestversion); 

if(!appversion.equals(latestversion))
{            
    System.out.println("not the same"); 
}
```

However this is giving me unexpected results given the outputs:

```
app version: v1.1.2 latest version: v1.1.2
not the same
```

I have used `.replaceAll("\\s","");` to remove any whitespaces from the strings with no success.

There is probably a very obvious answer to this but can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you just try appVersion.trim().equals(latestVersion.trim())? If that doesn't work,then add toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() to that trim() call on both the strings and see :)

Comment: You havn't posted how you have created `appversion`  and `latestversion` and assigned string values to them.

Comment: Use trim() method to remove white space .

Comment: Thanks for your replies, trim() doesn't work either. @Arun must be right something is going wrong when i'm assigning the variables. appversion is set as follows: `appversion = getVersionNumber(MainActivity.this);` and latestversion is set from a HttpResponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of .replaceAll() method, use trim() method to remove white space while comparing String variables.

change your code as follows as,

```
if(!appversion.trim().equals(latestversion.trim()))
{            
    System.out.println("not the same"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using .trim() on both Strings?

Comment: Sorry, i don't have enough reputation to be able to add comments.

Answer (score 0):

buddy try this

```
System.out.println("app version: "+ appversion.trim() + " latest version:"+latestversion.trim()); 

if(!appversion.trim().equals(latestversion.trim()))
{            
    System.out.println("not the same"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is running fine:-

```
 String appversion=" v1.1.2";
      String latestversion=" v1.1.2";
      if(!appversion.equals(latestversion))
      {            
      System.out.println("not the same"); 
      }
```

Or you can use:-

```
if(!appversion.trim().equals(latestversion.trim()))
```